# How to run the source code for com.android.browser?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I downloaded the source code from github.com for standard android browser:

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser

I opened the project in Eclipse. It showed me a lot of mistakes, mostly related to not connected libraries, but there are errors related to the fact that the class is connected but the corresponding method that is invoked in the class doesnt. Incidentally, it should be noted that when opening the project through File -> New -> Android Project -> then put the tab Create project from existing source and selecting the column Location path to the source com.android.browser, it is not selected version of Android, under which the program is written in the graph Build Target and have it set itself, I tried to choose one by one all and still having the same error.
Here is a partial list of classes that are not found:

```
import android.net.WebAddress;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.os.ServiceManager;
import android.text.IClipboard;
import android.os.ServiceManager;
import android.text.IClipboard;
import android.speech.RecognizerResultsIntent;
```

etc.

The same methods were not found or variables connected to the following classes:

```
Browser.getVisitedLike (cr, url)
Browser.BookmarkColumns.THUMBNAIL
Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_THUMBNAIL_INDEX
```

etc.

I tried to look for com.android.browser on other sites, everything that I found showed me the similar pattern. Can someone explain what the problem is, because all of the standard libraries and classes exist but the project is not created?
I tried to use the Hidden API, as shown on this page:

http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

downloaded from there the platform Hidden API, tried to compile them, some bugs got solved, but more than half the errors still remain.

Please help me figure out how to compile browser from the source code.

Answer (score 1):

The browser project is designed to be built in the context of the entire Android Open Source Project framework. It will not build with just the client App SDK that you have installed.

If you wish to build this browser, you will need to download the complete Android OS project to provide the correct environment.

You may want to look for a different browser (such as Firefox) which is open source and is not so tightly integrated into the OS.